# Why does my Sweetalert disappear when it appears

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, reload, sweetalert

I want to use sweetalert on my page. The problem is that following the successful operation, the sweetalert appears which is below, and when the OK button is clicked, the page must to be reload (). However, with sweetalert disappears as it appears and the page is reload (). therefore, I don't want the page to be reload () before I click the OK button. What should I do?

Edit Note: I'm using `ckeditor` on my page. I think the problem stems from `ckeditor`'s editing of `textareas`. but still i don't know how to solve it.

```
success: function (response) {
                        if (response.Result) {
                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Ok',
                                text: response.Mesage,
                                type: 'success',
                                showCancelButton: false,
                                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                                confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                            }).then(
                                function () {
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            )
                        }
                        else {
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Error',
                                response.Message,
                                'error')
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it's because your 'then' is firing regardless of the 'result' from the click.

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
      window.location.reload();  //i.e. if 'confirm' is pressed
  }
})
```

source: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: I tried it before but the same problem repeated. The problem is not "then". I tried without "then" but still the page was reload ().